# The most recent post of custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to get the most recent post of the taxonomy term 'featured-layout' within the taxonomy 'value_category'. The following code is returning all the 'featured-layouts' when I'm only wanting to return the most recent:

```
<?php

$cat_arr = array(
  'test-1',
  'test-2',
  'test-3',
);

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'values',
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
);

$mobile_posts = get_posts($args);
$count = 0;

foreach ($mobile_posts as $mobile_post) : setup_postdata($mobile_post);

  //Getting 'Featured' Value
  $featured_value_cat_query = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type' => 'values',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
          'taxonomy'   => 'value_layout_position',
          'field'      => 'slug',
          'terms'      => 'featured-layout',
        ),
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'value_category',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => $cat_arr,
        ),
    ),
  ) );

  if ( $featured_value_cat_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $featured_value_cat_query->have_posts() ): $featured_value_cat_query->the_post();

      echo ' | ' . the_title();

    endwhile;

  }

endforeach;

wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Does anyone know how to only return the most recent post from the 'featured-layout' term? Thanks!

Comment: It does not run with just 1 post :(

Answer (score 0):

Because your `posts_per_page` has a value of **-1** means return all matching query.

You should update your `post_per_page` to **1** and specify the `order`, and `orderby` parameters. Order the posts by date in descending order.

```
$featured_value_cat_query = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type' => 'values',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'date', // 
    'order' => 'DESC'
    ...
```

You can also learn more about the WP_Query [Order and OrderBy Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I did try that but for some reason it only returns one post from 'test-1' when it should be returning posts for 'test-2' and 'test-3'.

Comment: It only returns **one** item because of the `posts_per_page` value set to 1. How do you define recent posts in your blog, within a week, 3 days, or the last 3 posts?

Comment: In terms of `posts_per_page` , are you talking about when I use it within `$args` or `$featured_value_cat_query` ?

Comment: What I wanted to know now, is how do you personally define the recent posts? Basically recent posts involves filtration from dates. Does it mean that your recent post could be the posts posted less than a week old? How do you define it?

Comment: Gotcha. I haven't defined the recent post so I guess it's using whatever the default setting is. I personally define recent post as being the most recent post (not trying to be a smart ass here ;)  It's returning recent posts at the beginning of the loop but I only want to return the single most recent post with 'featured-layout' for 'test-1', 'test-2', and 'test-3'